# Cannot keep slack app disabled

Tags: force-stop, samsung-galaxy-s-20

I have a galaxy 20 ultra and I have repeatedly force-stopped the slack app, but it keep restarting on its own.  I believe this is happening to some other apps, but I can't recall the others at the moment.  Is there something I'm missing here to keep a force-stopped app stopped??

Comment: Apps can start automatically on certain times or events. Android is not like other OS used on desktops. If you want to keep an app quiet you should check it's options if there is for example a setting for defining work and non-work hours. Alternatively you could try to enable battery optimization for slack app, that should keep it closed while in background.

Answer (score 0):

Slack either uses play services APIs or wakelocks to restart itself. If you're rooted, you've got solutions such as the 'super freeze' app, otherwise practically nothing (There exists apps that doesn't require root and does force stop apps automatically after every wakeup but practically since the app  restarts itself after a while, you would end up getting even more battery drain)